# background size on a svg

Tags: html, css, svg

today wanted to set the size of a background on a svg using the `background-size` property, but it didn't worked because the background wasn't an image, but it was a normal color (#ecf2f8)

here is what i want to do: [image: what i wanted to do]

here is what i did: [image: what i did]

here is my code:

```css
#svg-social {
      position: absolute;
      right: 50px;
      bottom: 45px;
      background-color: #ecf2f8;
      border-radius: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<p id="main-text">
      Ever been in a room and felt like something was missing?<br> Perhaps 
      it felt slightly bare and uninviting. I’ve got some<br> simple tips 
      to help you make any room feel complete.</p>
      <div id="author">
        <img src="/images/avatar-michelle.jpg" alt="Michelle Appleton avatar" id="avatar">
        <h5 id="name">Michelle Appleton</h5>
        <p id="date">28 Jun 2020</p>
      </div>
    
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13" id="svg-social">
    
    
        <path fill="#6E8098"
          d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
      </svg>
      
      <div id="socials">
        <div id="triangle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you post all your code, including the html that generates the SVG to make your code reproducible (we can run it and check ourselves)?

Comment: I would use a viewBox for the svg element like `viewBox="-5 -5 25 25"` . If you opt for the viewBox solution please delete the height of the svg element. You can also choose a different width. Please read more about the [viewBox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `padding` to increase the size of the background around your element:

```
#svg-social {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 45px;
  background-color: #ecf2f8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The `px` value you pick depends on what you want, just play around with different values and see if it gets your desired output.

Example code snippet with padding in CSS:

```css
#svg-social {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 45px;
  background-color: #ecf2f8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>while</title>
 </head>

<body>

<p id="main-text">
  Ever been in a room and felt like something was missing?<br> Perhaps 
  it felt slightly bare and uninviting. I’ve got some<br> simple tips 
  to help you make any room feel complete.</p>
  <div id="author">
    <img src="/images/avatar-michelle.jpg" alt="Michelle Appleton avatar" id="avatar">
    <h5 id="name">Michelle Appleton</h5>
    <p id="date">28 Jun 2020</p>
  </div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13" id="svg-social">


    <path fill="#6E8098"
      d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
  </svg>
  
  <div id="socials">
    <div id="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Html-css-js snippet of code: [Code](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3Ewhile%3C/title%3E%0A%20%3C/head%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%20i$*$d=%22main-text%22%3E%0A%20%20Ever%20been%20in%20a%20room%20and%20felt%20like%20something%20was%20missing?%3Cbr%3E%20Perhaps%20%0A%20%20it%20felt%20slightly%20bare%20and%20uninviting.%20I%E2%80%99ve%20got%20some%3Cbr%3E%20simple%20tips%20%0A%20%20to%20help%20you%20make%20any%20room%20feel%20complete.%3C/p%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20i$*$d=%22author%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22/images/avatar-michelle.jpg%22%20alt=%22Michelle%20Appleton%20avatar%22%20i$*$d=%22avatar%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch5%20i$*$d=%22name%22%3EMichelle%20Appleton%3C/h5%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20i$*$d=%22date%22%3E28%20Jun%202020%3C/p%3E%0A%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20wi$*$dth=%2215%22%20height=%2213%22%20i$*$d=%22svg-social%22%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20fill=%22#6E8098%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20d=%22M15%206.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33%203.88%200%207.039%200%2010.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59%2010.294%205.422%209.11%208.39%209.11h.375v3.867L15%206.495z%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3C/svg%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20i$*$d=%22socials%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20i$*$d=%22triangle%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E&css=/*%20CSS%20styles%20*/%0Ah1%20%7B%0Afont-family:%20Impact,%20sans-serif;%0Acolor:%20#CE5937;%0A%7D%0A#svg-social%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20right:%2050px;%0A%20%20bottom:%2045px;%0A%20%20background-color:%20#ecf2f8;%0A%20%20border-radius:%20100px;%0A%20%20padding:%2010px;%0A%7D&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20%20=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A)

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't worked, it increased the background, but now it isn't showing the icon, it's like just a circle

Comment: @T69 weird, it works in the code snippet as well as on html-css-js.com. Did you remove anything else perhaps?

Comment: i copied and pasted your code

Comment: @T69 what happens if you removed the `padding` field from the copy/pasted code?

Comment: what do you mean? Now i deleted padding and obviusly it came back like it was before posting the question

Comment: @T69 If you changed padding to only `1px`, does that also remove the arrow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240659/discussion-between-t69-and-ryan-millares).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `padding` to resize the background of your icon. You can also resize the SVG icon by using `transform: scale(1);`

```css
#svg-social {
      position: absolute;
      right: 50px;
      bottom: 45px;
      background-color: #ecf2f8;
      border-radius: 100px;
      padding: .5em; /* You could also use px */
      transform: scale(1.5); /*Resize/scale the SVG*/
    }
```

```html
<p id="main-text">
      Ever been in a room and felt like something was missing?<br> Perhaps 
      it felt slightly bare and uninviting. I’ve got some<br> simple tips 
      to help you make any room feel complete.</p>
      <div id="author">
        <img src="/images/avatar-michelle.jpg" alt="Michelle Appleton avatar" id="avatar">
        <h5 id="name">Michelle Appleton</h5>
        <p id="date">28 Jun 2020</p>
      </div>
    
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13" id="svg-social">
    
    
        <path fill="#6E8098"
          d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
      </svg>
      
      <div id="socials">
        <div id="triangle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I added `padding` and `transform:scale()` in the CSS, please do check the snippet if it is your desired output

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div and add the background to the div, because i don't know why, with the padding property the svg disappears, here is the code:

```
  <div id="svg1">
<svg id="arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="13">
  <path fill="#6E8098"
    d="M15 6.495L8.766.014V3.88H7.441C3.33 3.88 0 7.039 0 10.936v2.049l.589-.612C2.59 10.294 5.422 9.11 8.39 9.11h.375v3.867L15 6.495z" />
</svg>
  </div>

 #svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 45px;
  background-color: #ecf2f8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
 #arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* this will center the svg in the div horizontally and vertically */
```